# How to find if the elements in a list are in ascending order or in descending order without using sort function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

The question which was given to me in python is , Accept a list with n number of terms and check if whether the elements are in ascending order , descending order or not in order without using sort function and def too.

Please Help me in doing this program.

Code:

```
a=list(input("Enter elements:"))
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i):
        if a[j]<=a[j+1]:
            print("It is in ascending order")
        elif a[j]>=a[j+1]:
            print("It is in descending order")
        else:
            print("It is not in order")
```

Comment: `all(a<b for a,b in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:]))`

Comment: @splash58 Good logic, but it will work only for ascending order. To extend it for both ascending and descending, ```all([(a<=b or a>=b)for a,b in zip(lst[:-1], lst[1:])])```

Comment: @SatheeshK No OP need ask ones more about desc. Your expression never returns false - (a<=b or a>=b) is always true

Comment: @splash58, Yes, you are right. So the answer would be ```all([a<=b for a,b in zip(lst3[:-1], lst3[1:])]) or all([a>=b for a,b in zip(lst3[:-1], lst3[1:])])```

Comment: @SatheeshK I've written the answer with one pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def which_order(list1):
    isAscending = True
    isDescending = True
    for i in range(1,len(list1)):
        if(list1[i] >= list1[i-1]):
            isDescending = False
        elif(list1[i] <= list1[i-1]):
            isAscending = False
        if((not isAscending) and (not isDescending)):
            print("The list is not sorted in either order.")
            break
    if(isAscending):
        print("The list is sorted in ascending order.")
    if(isDescending):
        print("The list is sorted in descending order.")
```

Sample output:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [9,8,7,6]
list3 = [1,9,8,7,6]
which_order(list1)
which_order(list2)
which_order(list3)

The list is sorted in ascending order.
The list is sorted in descending order.
The list is not sorted in either order.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def function(array):
    # check if array of length 1 so it will be mix order
    if len(array) == 1:
        print("It is not in order")
    
    # use constants to check nature of list 
    ascending_count = 0
    decending_count = 0
    
    for a, b in zip(array, array[1:]):
        if a>=b:
            # increase count if decending
            decending_count += 1
        else:
            # increase count if ascending
            ascending_count += 1
        # if both ascending and decending then it is mix 
        if ascending_count and decending_count:
            print("It is not in order")
            break
    
    if decending_count > 0 and ascending_count == 0 :
        print("It is in descending order")
    elif ascending_count > 0 and decending_count == 0:
        print("It is in ascending order")
        

function([1,2,3,4,5])
function([5,4,3,2,1])
function([1,2,3,1,2])
```

output

```
It is in ascending order
It is in descending order
It is not in order
```

Comment: Thanks for the program dear friend but can we do the program without def 
?

Comment: i wrote this way , so u can check any no of list , if you want to use in seperate way then remove first line and indent other llines , instead of return use print

Comment: This gives the expected output but is very inefficient: if you have a list with one billion values starting with `[0, 2, 1,  .....]`, your code will iterate twice over a billion values, though the output (neither ascending nor descending) can be decided after looking at the first three values.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i wrote this code according to OP need and easy to understand for him, consider if first three value are same then ?  cant decide based on that only, i can optimise it more if  require, plus one need to traverse to see all value and tell whether ti is full ascending or decending or none